# Given $g(x)$, find $f(x)$, knowing $f(x) = \sum_{a=1}^x g(a)$

Tags: functions, summation

Given $g(x)$, find $f(x)$, knowing $f(x) = \sum\limits_{a=1}^x g(a)$

Is there a universal approach of finding $f(x)$, regardless of $g(x)$? For simplicity sake, assuming that $g(x)$ is a polynomial function and $x > 1$.

For example, given $g(x) = 16x^2 + 4x + 4$, find a function $f(x)$, such that $f(x) =  \sum\limits_{a=1}^x g(a)$

The answer is $f(x) = \frac{16x^3}{3} + 10x^2 + \frac{26x}{3}$

But I'm not sure how that function is derived.

Comment: The answer given is not correct. Take $x=100$ for example then $f(100) \approx 100001$, but $\sum_{a=1}^{100} g(a) = 5434200$.

Comment: Let me take a look, I might have written one of them incorrectly

Comment: @ashimashi $f$ must be wrong, the sum of polynomial terms will still be a polynomial.

Comment: I get $f(n) = 16\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + 4\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 4n$

Comment: I got the problem from: https://projecteuler.net/problem=28

I wanted to see if I can find something that would work regardless of the function

Comment: For polynomials, please see [Faulhaber's Formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: @Winther and Alex, yes I had written the function incorrectly. it is fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a polynomial, it suffices WLOG that $g$ is a monomial, $g(x) = x^k$ then
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^x n^k$$
Then
$$f_k(x) = \frac1{k+1} \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \binom{k+1}j B_j n^{k+1-j}$$
by [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). (Thanks @André Nicolas for finding)
For a given polynomial $g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^j$ we get
$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j f_j(x)$$

For completely unknown functions, there's really no way you can tell what the result will be other than manually handling specific $g$.

Comment: Fantastic. It seems like what I was looking for! Thank you both!